# How do I move Buttons with my mouse (tkinter)

Tags: tkinter, button

Title basically explains it all. I want to move a button in tkinter with my mouse while the window is open. How do I do it??
Movement does'nt have to be exact...just approximate

Literally have no idea where to start :( Pls help

Comment: Learn about the `bind` command, and the `<ButtonPress-1>`, `Button-Release-1>` and `<B1-Motion>` events.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to move the button, search for "tkinter draggable widget" or "tkinter drag and drop example".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to move a button in tkinter with my mouse while the window is
> open. How do I do it??

Use `Button.bind`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MoveButton:
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text=f'move the button')
        self.button.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.pressed)
        self.button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.release)

    def pressed(self, e):
        self.button.bind("<Motion>", self.move)

    def release(self, e):
        self.button.unbind("<Motion>")

    def move(self, event: tk.Event):
        m_pos_x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
        m_pos_y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
        self.button.place(x=m_pos_x, y=m_pos_y)


root = tk.Tk()
bl = MoveButton()
root.mainloop()
```